# sed, xargs and stdbuf - how to get only first n matches of a pattern from a file

Tags: sed, xargs

I have a file with patterns (1 line=1 pattern) I want to look for on a big text file -  only one (or none) pattern will be found in each line of the infile. Once found a match, I want to retrieve the characters immediately before the match. The first part is to acquire the patterns for sed

```
cat patterns.txt | xargs -I '{}' sed -n 's/{}.*$//p' bigtext.txt
```

That works ok - the downside being that potentially I'll have hundreds of thousands of matches. I don't want/need all the matches - a fair representation of 1K hits would be enough. And here is where I struggle: I've read that in order to limit the number of hits of sed, I should use `stdbuf` (`gstdbuf` in my case) and pipe the whole thing through head. But I am not sure where to place the `stdbuf` command:

```
cat patterns.txt | xargs -I '{}' gstdbuf -oL -eL sed -n 's/{}.*$//p' bigtext.txt | head -n100
```

When I tried this, the process takes as long as if it was running sed on the whole file and then getting the `head` of that output, while my wish is to stop searching after 100 or 1000 matches. Any ideas on the best way of accomplishing this?

Comment: `awk` can natively manage counters. Do you have to use `sed`? Good luck.

Comment: No, not necessarily. Any pointers on how to process this using `awk`?

Comment: Can you show minimal input, pattern and desired output files?

Comment: Sure. Let's be the pattern 

    `echo -e "AGCC \nAGTT \nCGTT" > pattern.txt` . 

And the query file

    `echo -e "1aaaAGCC1 \n2aaabbbAGCC2 \n3aaacccAGCC3 \n4aaaAGTT1  \n5aaaAGTT2 \n3aaaAGTT3 \n1aaaCGTT1 \n2aaaCGTT2 \n3aaaCGTT3"  > query.txt`

My desired output would be, limited to 5 matches

`1aaa
2aaabbb
3aaaccc
4aaa
5aaa`

Comment: look at `grep -Ff patternFile.txt *files2Search*`, On some systems it also works as `fgrep -f patFile *f2Src*`. Good luck.

Comment: In the future, include your sample data and required output in the body of your Q. We're not mind readers ;-) . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Is the oneliner you have provided really what you wanted? Esp. since you mention a fair sample. Because as it is stands right now, it feeds `patterns.txt` into `xargs`... which will go ahead and invoke `sed` for each pattern individually, one after another. And the whole output of `xargs` is fed to head which chops it of after `n` lines. In other words, your first pattern can already exhaust all the lines you wanted to see, even though the other patterns could have matched any number of times on lines occurring before the matches presented to you. Detailed example between  horizontal rulers.

---

If I have `patterns.txt` of:

```
_Pat1
_Pat2
_Pat3
```

And `bigtext.txt` with:

```
1matchx_Pat1x
2matchx_Pat2x 
2matchy_Pat2y 
2matchz_Pat2z 
3matchx_Pat3x 
3matchy_Pat3y 
3matchz_Pat3z
1matchy_Pat1y 
1matchz_Pat1z
```

And I run your oneliner limited to five hits, I do not get result of (first five matches for all three patterns as found in the file):

```
1matchx
2matchx
2matchy
2matchz
3matchx
```

But (all (3) patches for `_Pat1` plus 2 matches for `_Pat2` after which I've ran out of output lines):

```
1matchx
1matchy
1matchz
2matchx
2matchy
```

---

Now to your performance problem which is partially related. I have to admit that I could not reproduce it. I've taken your example from the comment, blew the "big" file up to a 1GB in size by repeating the pattern and ran your oneliner:

```
$ time { cat patterns.txt | xargs -I '{}' stdbuf -oL sed -n 's/{}.*$//p' bigtext.txt | head -5 ; }
1aaa
2aaabbb
3aaaccc
1aaa
2aaabbb
xargs: stdbuf: terminated by signal 13

real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.008s
```

Note I've dropped the `-eL`, stderr is usually unbuffered (which is what you usually want) and doesn't play any role here really. Also note I've ran `stdbuf` without the "g" prefix, which tells me you're probably on a system where GNU tools are not the default... and probably the reasons why you get different behavior. I'll try to explain what is going on and venture few guesses... and conclude with a suggestion. Also note, I really did not need to use `stdbuf` (manipulate buffering) at all or rather it had no appreciable impact on the result, but again, this could be platform and tools (as well as scenario) specific.

When you read the line from its end, `head` reads standard input as it is being piped in from `xargs` (and by extension the `sed` (or `stdbuf` wrapping) runs which `xargs` forks, they are both attached to its writing end) until limit of lines to print has been reached and then `head` terminates. Doing so "breaks" the pipe and `xargs` and `sed` (or `stdbuf` which it was wrapped in) receive `SIGPIPE` signal and by default they as well terminate (that you can see in the output of my run: `xargs: stdbuf: terminated by signal 13`).

What the `stdbuf -oL` does and why someone might have suggested it. When no longer using console for reading/writing, which would usually be line buffered, and using pipes we would usually see buffered I/O instead. `stdbuf -oL` changes that back to line buffered. Without it, the process involved would communicate in larger chunk and it could take `head` longer to realize, it is done and needs no further input, while `sed` keeps running to see if there are any further suitable matches. As mentioned, on my systems (4K buffer) and with that (repeating pattern) example, this made no real difference. Also note, while it decreases the risk of not knowing we could be done, line buffering does increase overhead involved in communication between the processes.

So why would these mechanics not yield the same expected results for you? Couple options come to mind:

- since you fork and run `sed` once per pattern, whole file each time. It could happen you get series of several runs without any hits. I'd guess this is actually likely the case.
- since you give `sed` file to read from, you may have different implementation of `sed` that tries to read a lot more in before taking action on the file content (mine reads 4K at a time). Not a likely cause, but in theory you could also feed `sed` line by line to force smaller chunks and getting that `SIGPIPE` sooner.

Now assuming that sequential pattern by pattern matching is actually not desired, summary of all of above would be: process your patterns first into a single one and then perform a single pass over the "big" file (optionally capping the output of course). It might be worth switching from shell mostly to something a bit more comfortable to use, or at least not to keep the oneliner format which is likely to turn confusing.

---

Not true to my own recommendation, `awk` script called like this prints first 5 hits and quits:

```
awk -v patts="$(cat patterns.txt)" -v last=5 'BEGIN{patts="(" patts ; gsub(/\n/, "|", patts) ; sub(/.$/, ")", patts); cnt=1 ;} $0~patts{sub(patts ".*", ""); print; cnt++;} cnt>last{exit;}' bigtext.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response - There is a lot there for me to chew but a couple of pointers: 
You are right that the output I am getting is not a fair sample of the pattern.txt file - It will probably be wiser to keep record of the matches of each pattern? Now that I think about it, replacing the \n in the pattern file by spaces will be wiser - and will only require the bigfile to be loaded once. It will also return a more fair sample of the output as the order of ocurrence of the patterns in the bigfile is random.

Comment: Second, the performance related issue comes with the length of each pattern (120 characters)  and each line of the bigfile ( 250 characters, 10 GB file size). Thanks again and will get back to you

Comment: Please note, spaces won't do if you wanted to match regex in a single pass. For that, you would need to separate them with or (`\|` depending on `|' regex style, standard and extended resp.). Check out the awk example at the bottom t of the post (yes, brevity is not really my strength ;) ) that prepares this collective pattern from the current one pattern per line file.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a file that has patterns to match to the grep command with a `-f file`. You can also specify the number of matches to find before quiting `-m count`

So this command will get you the first 5 lines that match:

```
grep -f patterns.txt -m 5  bigtext.txt
```

Now to trim the match to the end of the line, is a bit more difficult.
Assuming you use bash, we can build a regex from the file, like this:

```
  while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    subRegex="s/$line.*//;"${subRegex}
  done < patterns.txt
```

Then use this in a sed command. The resulting code becomes:

```
  while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    subRegex="s/$line.*//;"${subRegex}
  done < patterns.txt
  grep -f patterns.txt -m 5  bigtext.txt | sed "$subRegex"
```

The sed command is only running on the lines that have already matched from the grep, so it should be fairly performant.

Now if you call this a lot you could put it in a function

```
function findMatches() {
  local matchCount=${1:-5}  # default to 5 matches
  local subRegex

  while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    subRegex="s/$line.*//;"${subRegex}
  done < patterns.txt

  grep -f patterns.txt -m ${matchCount}  bigtext.txt | sed "${subRegex}"
}
```

Then you can call it like this

```
findMatches 5
findMatches 100
```

**Update**

Based on the sample files you gave, this solution does produce the expected result `1aaa 2aaabbb 3aaaccc 4aaa 5aaa`

However, given your comment on the length of each pattern being 120 characters, and each line of the bigfile being 250 characters, 10 GB file size.

You didn't mention how many patterns you might have. So I tested and it seems that the sed command done inline falls apart someplace before 50 patterns.

(Of course, if your samples are really how the data look, then you could do your trimming of each line to be based bases on non-AGCT and not based on the patterns file. Which would be much quicker)

But based on the original question. You can generate a sed script in a separate file based on patterns.txt. Like this:

```
  sed -e "s/^/s\//g;s/$/.*\$\/\/g/g;" patterns.txt > temp.sed
```

then use this temp file on the sed command.

```
 grep -f patterns.txt -m 5 bigtext.txt | sed -f temp.sed
```

The grep stops after finding X matches, and the sed trims those... The new function runs on my machine in a **couple seconds**.
For testing I created a 2GB file of 250 character AGCT combos. And another file with 50+ patterns, 120 characters each with a few of these patterns taken from random lines of the bigtext file.

```
function findMatches() {
  sed -e "s/^/s\//g;s/$/.*\$\/\/g/g;" patterns.txt > temp.sed
  grep -f patterns.txt -m ${1:-5}   bigtext.txt | sed -f temp.sed
}
```